# Is connect_reclaim_url still available, even as Graph API?

Tags: facebook, url

I'm not able to find any information about `connect_reclaim_url` listed as a parameter of the [Application object in the Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appproperties/) , and how it should work? I suppose there are two main variations:

1. On every app (allow / cancel) request the url will be set for the user (this I think is not the way)
2. There is a general URL set whether on the app dashboard (I coulnd't find where, yet) or via API and the UID will be passed when the user deletes it's FB profile

Can someone confirm one of the above. Even a little description how to do that properly or sites that describes this.

Comment: I don’t even have any idea, what “custom_reclaim_url” is supposed to _be_ … Could you elaborate a little more, on where you found that term?

Comment: Wow, i've never seen that parameter used before - `connect_reclaim_url` is listed as an application property, but i don't know what it does - i can check later when i get to the office

Answer (score 0):

It’s not really a parameter/property of the Application object in the (current) *Graph API* – the linked docs refer to the old Rest API.

And the description of that property does not make much sense to me, either:

> *“For Facebook-enabled websites, the URL you can provide to reclaim an account from a user who deactivated his or her Facebook account.”*

Why would I want to “reclaim” their account, and what would I do with it afterwards …?

> There is a general URL set whether on the app dashboard (I coulnd't find where, yet) or via API and the UID will be passed when the user deletes it's FB profile

The only thing that comes close to that in the current API is the `deauth_callback_url` – *“URL that is pinged whenever a user removes the app”*

Via this, you can get notified if a user removes your app from their account settings. If this is also pinged when a user deletes their FB account or disables all apps on the platform, I don’t know exactly. (I’d definitively expect it for the latter case, and it’d make sense for the first one, too.)

Comment: To answer your question, there is a very simple workflow when the user actually removes his/her account from Facebook (whatever reason) and I want him anyway as a registered user on my site. I want to offer him a possibility to enter to my site with a normal registration form. You mentioned the `deauth_callback_url` which in case of account removal will be triggered as well. I couldn't test it completely because I'm not that familiar with sandboxing mode of FB.